# Mysql decrease value from another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables: `user_values` and `decrease_times`.

`user_values` has 3 columns: `username, property, value` and `decrease_times` has 3 columns: `property, decrease_value, decrease_time`. All of these are dynamic and change a lot.

I have a cron job that gets called every hour, and what I want to do is reduce all the `value` rows from `user_values` with the amount stored in `decrease_value` if `property` from `user_values` is equal to `property` from `decrease_times`.

Also, `decrease_time` can be 0 or 1, 0 means it should decrease every 1 hour, and 1 means it should decrease every 24 hours. I already implemented an if-clause that detects if it is 6am, and then it should decrease all the values if they are 1 or 0.

What query should I make to do this? Also, this is done in PHP.

**Edit:** What I did so far is this: `UPDATE user_values SET value = value - (SELECT decrease_value FROM decrease_times WHERE property=/* property from UPDATE clase should be here */) WHERE property=(SELECT property FROM decrease_times WHERE decrease_time=0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use a select statement anywhere...

```
UPDATE user_values AS values 
INNER JOIN decrease_times AS times ON values.property = times.property 
SET values.value = values.value-times.decrease_value
WHERE values.property = times.property AND times.decrease_time = 0
```

You are taking your table you're looking to edit, and joining it for the query with the second table... You set the value field on your user_values table using the simple maths equation you need, and ensure that both the property values are the same, and that you're only updating the rows that are meant to be updated every hour.

Your daily version would be the same, but wouldn't need "AND..." onwards

Answer (score -1):

something like this `UPDATE TABLE SET your_value=(your_value-1) WHERE USERID=5`

or

`UPDATE TABLE1 SET your_value=(your_value +(SELECT your_value2+5 FROM TABLE2 WHERE USERID=5)) WHERE USERID=5`

-- adapt it to your needs; this is basic SQL syntax.

Need better example and your table structure -- you can use http://sqlfiddle.com/ and recreate some of your tables/data so we can play with it

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Comment: That doesn't help too much as I don't want to reduce my value by one, but by the amount in another table.

Comment: Then select your another table in the UPDATE clause

Comment: The table structure is all laid out...it doesn't need explaining any better than how @Pacha has. For a start the Table is not TABLE1, it's user_values...

Comment: The thing is that I should select the `decrease_value` from the UPDATE clause and pass it to the SELECT clause. That is where my main problem is. I am going to edit my question and add that.